# OpenCV affectation

Tags: c++, opencv

Why can't I do something like this:

```
cv::Mat img = imread("path/to/image1");
cv::Mat img2 = imread("path/to/image2");
img.ptr<uchar>(0,0) = img2.ptr<uchar>(0,0);
```

I get this message from VS : expression must be a modifiable lvalue

So instead I had to resort to doing something like this:

```
img.ptr<uchar>(0,0)[0] = img2.ptr<uchar>(0,0)[0];
```

And affect each channel, it doesn't bother me but I'd like to know why I can't do the other one.

Answer (score -1):

The = operator would need to know what kind of image it was and would need complicated code for planar image types.

You can use the [CV_IMAGE_ELEM](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/faq_technical.html?highlight=cv_image_elem) macro